# How to access a key of an object by its variable name in DOM using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have a controller which adds to scope a variable called `comments`

```
$scope.showComments = function(id){
    dataService.getComments(id).then(function(data){
        $scope.comments[id] = data.comments;
        console.log($scope.comments);
    });
}
```

I want to call the ng-repeat on a specific id. The following method is not working. Any ideas?

```
<div class="commentsContainer" id="{{id}}">
    <div class="eachcomment" ng-repeat="comment in comments.{{id}}">
        <p>{{comment.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The desired id is given to the outer div. But `ng-repeat` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **filter** to achieve this functionality as follows:

```
<div class="eachcomment" ng-repeat="comment in comments | filterId: id">
    <p>{{comment.content}}
</div>
```

Now, write a filter:

```
app.filter('filterId', function(){
    return function(collection, id) {
        var output = [];
        angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
            if(item.id == id) {
                output.push(item)
            }
        })
        return output;
    }
})
```

Or you can use an **easier way**:

```
<div class="eachcomment" ng-repeat="comment in comments | filter: checkId">
        <p>{{comment.content}}
    </div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.checkId = function(item) {
    if($scope.id == item.id) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But this gives me the object with the ID as the key. How do I access the contents linked with the given ID. I do not know the ID beforehand.

Comment: While your ng-repeat is running, your $scope.id is set right?

Comment: This is running in another ng-repeat. So I am initializing a id for each element in outer repeat using ng-init.

Comment: Please create a plunker

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <div class="commentsContainer" id="{{id}}">
        <div class="eachcomment" ng-repeat="(key, comment) in comments">
            <p ng-show="key === id">{{comment.content}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.id = 0;
    $scope.comments = [{
        content: 'Hello'
    }, {
        content: 'World'
    }];

}]);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/vdaesax1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access property by variable key:

```
<div class="commentsContainer" id="{{id}}">
    <div class="eachcomment" ng-repeat="comment in comments[id]">
        <p>{{comment.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```